# How do I pause and resume a Synapse dedicated SQL pool automatically?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How do I pause and resume a Synapse dedicated SQL pool automatically? If it is in ideal state can I capture that and pause synapse dedicated SQL Pool?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the below query :

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests
WHERE status not in ('Completed','Failed','Cancelled')
AND session_id <> session_id()
ORDER BY submit_time DESC;
```

gives us whether there is any active queries running in SQL DW.
If not, then using the ADF REST API to pause SQL dw, you can pause the SQL DW via web activity.

Git hub ADF ARM template:
https://github.com/NandanHegde15/Azure-DataFactory-Generic-Pipelines/blob/main/Azure%20SQL%20DataWarehouse/PauseAzureSQLDW.json